# Stripping HTML elements

Tags: beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to migrate a webforum where I don't have control over database etc and uses Scrapy to pick the pieces. It is based on an old phpBB forum 2.x.
It is not very well structured so a few challenges.

I now have a HTML string where I need to remove surrounding `<td></td>`, `<span></span>`and the Report link at bottom

Starting with:

```
<td colspan="2"><span class="postbody"></span>
    <table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="genmed"><b>Some wrote :</b></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="quote">
                <table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="genmed"><b>Another wrote:</b></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="quote">Just for test
                            <a href="https://something.com">a link</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <span class="postbody">
                    <br>

                    <br>
                    Test quote #1</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <span class="postbody">
        <br>

        <br>
        Test quote #2<br>
        Another link: <a href="https://another.com">linktext</a><br>
        _________________<br>/ author
        <br>
        text<br>
        <div align="right">[ <a href="#" class="postlink" onclick="abuse('http://gt40.forum24.se/viewtopic.php?p=6537*6537&amp;forum=gt40');">Rapportera</a>
            ] </div>
    </span><span class="gensmall"></span>
</td>
```

Wanted result:

```
<table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="genmed"><b>Some wrote :</b></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="quote">
            <table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="genmed"><b>Another wrote:</b></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="quote">Just for test
                        <a href="https://something.com">a link</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <span class="postbody">
                <br>

                <br>
                Test quote #1</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<br>
Test quote #2<br>
Another link: <a href="https://another.com">linktext</a><br>
_________________<br>/ author
<br>
text<br>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply do

```
html = html.strip('<td colspan="2"><span class="postbody"></span>')
```

and

```
html = html.strip('</td>').strip().strip('</span>')
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with some string manipulations but didn't use strip(..) will look into it and see if that makes it even easier - looks lite it does. Thanks!